# Describing a singly articulated system with forces on the joints

Tags: kinematics

I am trying to understand a kinematics problem (that intuitively appears trivial at first glance), with the ultimate goal of simulating it.

Consider the following triangle (from Wikipedia).

[image: Triangle]

Assume $a$ and $c$ are rigid edges joined at the point $B$ with mass $m_B$, while $b$ is an elastic rubber band exerting a force on points $C$ with mass $m_C$ and $A$ with mass $m_A$, pulling them together.

This will intuitively exert a rotation on $a$ (counter-clockwise) and $c$ (clockwise), reducing $\beta$.

How do I correctly express this structure, and how do I calculate the motion of the points $A$, $B$ and $C$. I started by decomposing the force at one of the end-points into a tangential force. But now I wonder how $B$ will move. My suspicion is that it will move along a perpendicular to $b$, but I am unsure how to approach the whole problem.

Comment: You tagged the question as kinematics, but requiring "..the motion of points .." then it seems it is instead dynamics: which means that you shall consider the mass of $a$ and $c$, is it so ?

Comment: In fact I am uncertain which category this belongs to. Yes, the single points have mass. Please feel free to retag, if the tag kinematics was used incorrectly.

Comment: Is point _B_ pinned to the ground but allowed to rotate, or is the whole thing floating in space with no gravity, or is _AB_ fixed and just CB move? PS. I think this question is more suitable for [Physics.SE]. The equations of motion of an articulated system are quite complex actually.

Comment: I was thinking about physics, actually, but settled to post it here, finally.

No, B is not pinned at all. The whole thing is floating. I want to understand the problem first without gravity or a floor, but add them later.

Comment: I hope you are familiar with trigonometry, linear algebra, and vector calculus. The problem has 4 degrees of freedom that need to be identified in free body diagram in order to start solving it. Also the location of the center of mass of each rigid bar is important and needs noting in a diagram.

Comment: I am. I am just not familiar with this field.

Comment: Either fix link (side of triangle) $c$ and rotate $ a$  or  vice versa because the degree of freedom in motion of the mechanism should be $1$

Comment: @Narasimham - a mechanism can have more than one degree of freedom. In this case, there are four degrees of freedom, three to position and orient one bar and a fourth for the relative angle between bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following configuration and free body diagrams:

[image: ArtBars1]

Each bar is designated by the location of the center of mass ${\boldsymbol r}_1$, ${\boldsymbol r}_2$ and the orientation of the bar $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$. Above $\theta_1$ is positive and $\theta_2$ is negative (all angles measured CCW). The relative angle between the two bars is $\varphi = \theta_2 - \theta_1$.

At the joint *B*, equal and opposite forces act on the two bodies. No torque is passed through the joint.

The spring is a single force member, and it is replaced with the force $\| {\boldsymbol F}_s \| = k ( \| {\boldsymbol r}_C - {\boldsymbol r}_A || - \ell )$ at each time frame. As a vector, this force is along the *AC* direction.

$$ {\boldsymbol F}_s = \pmatrix{Fx_S \\ Fy_S} =  k ( \| {\boldsymbol r}_C - {\boldsymbol r}_A || - \ell ) \frac{ {\boldsymbol r}_C - {\boldsymbol r}_A}{ \| {\boldsymbol r}_C - {\boldsymbol r}_A\| } $$

<sub>Here $\ell$ is the free length of the spring</sub>

### Step 1 - Kinematics

Point *B* shares position, velocity, and acceleration between the two bodies. I assume you can find the position of *B* from the location of *G1* and the angle $\theta_1$, or the location of *G2* and the angle $\theta_2$.

- **Velocity** - At point *B*  $$ \begin{aligned} {\boldsymbol v}_2 + {\boldsymbol \omega}_2 \times ({\boldsymbol r}_B - {\boldsymbol r}_2) & = {\boldsymbol v}_1 + {\boldsymbol \omega}_1 \times ({\boldsymbol r}_B - {\boldsymbol r}_1) \\ \dot{\theta}_2 & = \dot{\theta}_1 + \dot{\varphi} \end{aligned} $$

Or as a system of equations:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & (y_2 - y_B) \\ 0 & 1 & -(x_2-x_B) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\dot{x}_2 \\ \dot{y}_2 \\ \dot{\theta}_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & (y_1 - y_B) \\ 0 & 1 & -(x_1-x_B) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{y}_1 \\ \dot{\theta}_1} + \pmatrix{0\\0\\ \dot{\varphi}}$$ (1)

- **Acceleration** - At point *B* (implicit derivative of velocity)

$$\begin{aligned} {\boldsymbol a}_2 + {\boldsymbol \alpha}_2 \times ({\boldsymbol r}_B-{\boldsymbol r}_2) + {\boldsymbol \omega}_2 \times ({\boldsymbol v}_B-{\boldsymbol v}_2) & ={\boldsymbol a}_1 + {\boldsymbol \alpha}_1 \times ({\boldsymbol r}_B-{\boldsymbol r}_1) + {\boldsymbol \omega}_1 \times ({\boldsymbol v}_B-{\boldsymbol v}_1) \\
 \ddot{\theta}_2 &=  \ddot{\theta}_1 + \ddot{\varphi} 
\end{aligned} $$

Or as a system of equations

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & (y_2 - y_B) \\ 0 & 1 & -(x_2-x_B) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\ddot{x}_2 \\ \ddot{y}_2 \\ \ddot{\theta}_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & (y_1 - y_B) \\ 0 & 1 & -(x_1-x_B) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\ddot{x}_1 \\ \ddot{y}_1 \\ \ddot{\theta}_1} + \pmatrix{0\\0\\ \ddot{\varphi}} + \pmatrix{\dot{y}_1 \dot{\theta}_1 - \dot{y}_2 \dot{\theta}_2 + \dot{y}_B \dot{\varphi} \\ -\dot{x}_1 \dot{\theta}_1 + \dot{x}_2 \dot{\theta}_2 - \dot{x}_B \dot{\varphi} \\ 0 }$$ (2)

<sub>Note that $\dot{x}$ is the first time derivative of $x$ and $\ddot{x}$ the 2nd derivative. A $\cdot$ is the inner product and $\times$ is the vector cross product.</sub>

### Step 2 - Kinetics

The equations of motion relate the motion of the center of mass with the net loading on each bar

- **Bar 1** - Equations of motion of bar [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvJT2.png) (green)

$$\require{cancel} \begin{aligned}
  {\boldsymbol F}_s - {\boldsymbol F}_B & = m_1 {\boldsymbol a}_1 \\
  ({\boldsymbol r}_A - {\boldsymbol r}_1) \times {\boldsymbol F}_s - ({\boldsymbol r}_B - {\boldsymbol r}_1) \times {\boldsymbol F}_B & = I_1 {\boldsymbol \alpha}_1 + \cancel{ {\boldsymbol \omega}_1 \times I_1 {\boldsymbol \omega}_1}
\end{aligned} $$

Or as a system of equations

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ (y_1-y_A) & -(x_1-x_A) & 1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{Fx_s\\Fy_s\\0} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ (y_1-y_B) & -(x_1-x_B) & 1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{B_x \\ B_y \\0}= \begin{bmatrix} m_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & m_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I_1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\ddot{x}_1 \\ \ddot{y}_1 \\ \ddot{\theta}_1 } $$ (3)

- **Bar 2** - Equations of motion of bar [2] (yellow)

$$\require{cancel} \begin{aligned}
  -{\boldsymbol F}_s + {\boldsymbol F}_B & = m_2 {\boldsymbol a}_2 \\
  -({\boldsymbol r}_C - {\boldsymbol r}_2) \times {\boldsymbol F}_s + ({\boldsymbol r}_B - {\boldsymbol r}_2) \times {\boldsymbol F}_B & = I_2 {\boldsymbol \alpha}_2 + \cancel{ {\boldsymbol \omega}_2 \times I_2 {\boldsymbol \omega}_2}
\end{aligned} $$

Or as a system of equations

$$-\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ (y_2-y_C) & -(x_2-x_C) & 1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{Fx_s\\Fy_s\\0} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ (y_2-y_B) & -(x_2-x_B) & 1 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{B_x \\ B_y \\0}= \begin{bmatrix} m_2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & m_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I_2 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\ddot{x}_2 \\ \ddot{y}_2 \\ \ddot{\theta}_2 } $$ (4)

Here $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the bars, and $I_1 = \frac{m_1}{12} \ell_1^2$ and $I_2 = \frac{m_2}{12} \ell_2^2$ are the mass moment of inertia of the bars about the center of mass.

### Step 3 - Solution

The set of equations (2), (3) and (4) present 9 equations in total. These are solved for the following 9 unknowns $\pmatrix{\ddot{x}_1 & \ddot{y}_1 & \ddot{\theta}_1}$,  $\pmatrix{\ddot{x}_2 & \ddot{y}_2 & \ddot{\theta}_2}$, $\pmatrix{B_x & B_y}$ and $\ddot{\varphi}$.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|cc|c}
m_{1} &  &  &  &  &  & 1 & \\
 & m_{1} &  &  &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  & I_{1} &  &  &  & -(y_{B}-y_{1}) & (x_{B}-x_{1})\\
\hline  &  &  & m_{2} &  &  & -1 & \\
 &  &  &  & m_{2} &  &  & -1\\
 &  &  &  &  & I_{2} & (y_{B}-y_{2}) & -(x_{B}-x_{2})\\
\hline 1 &  & -(y_{B}-y_{1}) & -1 &  & (y_{B}-y_{2}) &  & \\
 & 1 & (x_{B}-x_{1}) &  & -1 & -(x_{B}-x_{2}) &  & \\
 &  & 1 &  &  & -1 &  &  & 1
\end{array}\right]\left(\begin{array}{c}
\ddot{x}_{1}\\
\ddot{y}_{1}\\
\ddot{\theta}_{1}\\
\hline \ddot{x}_{2}\\
\ddot{y}_{2}\\
\ddot{\theta}_{2}\\
\hline B_{x}\\
B_{y}\\
\hline \ddot{\varphi}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
Fx_{S}\\
Fy_{S}\\
(x_{C}-x_{1})Fy_{S}-(y_{C}-y_{1})Fx_{S}\\
\hline -Fx_{S}\\
-Fy_{S}\\
-(x_{C}-x_{2})Fy_{S}+(y_{C}-y_{2})Fx_{S}\\
\hline (\dot{y}_{B}-\dot{y}_{1})\dot{\theta}_{1}-(\dot{y}_{B}-\dot{y}_{2})\dot{\theta}_{2}\\
(\dot{x}_{B}-\dot{x}_{2})\dot{\theta}_{2}-(\dot{x}_{B}-\dot{x}_{1})\dot{\theta}_{1}\\
0
\end{array}\right)$$

After all the accelerations are found, they need to be integrated over time using an $\mbox{ODE}$ solver appropriate for dynamics.

Comment: @bitmask - You have what you need to solve this problem.

Comment: I added all the equations as a 9×9 system of linear equations.

Comment: For $n$ bodies, you have $3n$ equations of motion, $3 (n-1)$ kinematic equations for $\mbox{#equ} = 3 (2n-1)$. You also have $3n$ body motion unknowns (linear & angular accelerations), $2(n-1)$ joint reaction forces and $(n-1)$ joint relative angle accelerations, for $\mbox{#vars} = 3(2n-1)\;\checkmark$ unnkowns.

Comment: This will take me a while to go though. But let me tell you in advance a big thank you for such a long and exhaustive answer!

Comment: Given the picture, did you get this or part of it from a textbook or something similar? Which one?

Comment: @bitmask - The sketches I drew up with PowerPoint of all things. The subject matter is actually of graduate level engineering (articulated mechanics) and I have such a degree in this field. Honestly, the most difficult part of this post was to expand it out in terms of vectors and their components. In robotics, we often use higher order mathematical constructs called Screws (which are two vectors making a 6×1 quantity). My final advice to you is to be verbose and consistent with notation first. A good system for describing things goes a long way to explain things.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. I'll let you know when I get awarded the [unsung hero](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero) badge. Oh, and if you have more questions, **please ask on [Physics.SE]** and not here.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a hint than a complete answer, but I hope it could be useful.

It is supposed that the triangle is laid on a horizontal plane, or however that it is not subject to gravity.
In this situation, the forces acting on it (once you take out your fingers) **are all internal**.

That means that the barycenter of the triangle does not translate, and that the total angular momentum is null.

Since the spring is considered to be massless, the total barycenter $G$ will lay on the segment $G_a G_c$, at the mass weighted
average distance.

[image: Dyn_Triangle_1]

Let's now take a reference frame linked to the triangle.
We can place the triangle with $G$ on the origin of the frame, and with the $x$ axis connecting the barycenters of the two edges.
Denoting by $x_a$ the abscissa of $G_a$, then we have that
 - the position of $G_c$ is fully determined;
 - the position of $B$ is determined by being at the crossing of the circles center $G_a$, radius $a/2$ and center $G_c$, radius $c/2$;
 - consequently are determined the position of $A$ and $C$.

Thus in this frame the only free variable is $x_a$.
To position this frame with respect to an external reference system we need to add a rotation 
around the vertical axis (call it $\Omega$), which will balance to $0$ the overall angular momentum.

At this point, this system with two degrees of freedom is a classical example that asks to be solved
by the Lagrangian Mechanics.
However, since it involves trigometric functions, it will be non-linear and same as for pendulum,
 you may think and solve it for small oscillations around equilibrium.

Comment: One of the two remaining DOF is a rotation about _G_. You'll have a hard time modeling rotations with perturbations/vibrations.

Comment: @ja72: do not get exactly what you mean. The kinetic energy can be expressed in terms of $\Omega$ and $x_a$, a bit complicated but not impossible. So the potential energy. But to solve the Lagrangian in the general case will be in fact not feasible, unless for small oscillations. You are using more coordinates: don't know if this is of advantage in the solution.